# Matching by beginning of a string or by a single character in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have two regular expressions:

```
/\/(\w\w+)/g
/(^\w\w+)/g
```

and am wondering if there's any way to combine them into a single regex?  Basically I want to find any part of a string that either starts with /, or is the beginning of the string, and then is a word with 2 or more characters in it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
/(?:^|\/)(\w{2,})/g
```

Use a non-capturing group to alternate between the starting conditions.
This will keep the capturing group number the same as in the originals too.